# Почему не перехватывается errno?

Tags: c, c++, linux

Здравствуйте! Нужно организовать определение того, что был выход из функции без функции-обработчика (с помощью errno). Мой код как всегда не работает. Что с ним не так?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

void alrm()
{
    // ничего нет, пустой обработчик...
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *s[80];
    signal(SIGALRM, alrm); // обработчик сигнала
    printf("Input name \n");
    alarm(2);
    for (;;) {
        if (read(0, s, 15) < 0 && errno == EINTR)
            exit(0);
        else
            break;

    }
    printf("%s", s);
    printf("OK! \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr)](/users/3147/alerr), для начала (и определенности).

Переменная **`errno`** устанавливается в **`EINTR`** (что Вы видимо ожидаете) не при получении процессом сигнала и вызове его обработчика, а при *прерывании системного вызова*.

Вы делаете `read` и ядро ждет ввода данных. Во время ожидания срабатывает таймер (`alarm(2)`) и генерится сигнал, который обрабатывается (вызывается Ваш обработчик `alrm`).

По умолчанию в Linux сигнал не прерывает системный вызов. read продолжит чтение и при поступлении данных вернется в программу. Для изменения такого поведения есть вызов `siginterrupt`. Просто напишите (до `read`)

```
siginterrupt(SIGALRM,1);
```

Это разрешает прерывание системного вызова и после него (прерванного) Вы получите `errno  == EINTR`. Кстати, если вместо signal вызывать sigaction и явно не устанавливать флаг `SA_RESTART` в поле .sa_flags, то вызовы **будут** прерываться.

Но, еще раз обращаю внимание, что `EINTR` присваивается `errno` **не по приходу/обработке сигнала**, а только в случае, если **выполнение системного вызова было прервано**.

Чтобы было понятнее, реально сигнал от вызова `alarm()` появится при обработке прерывания от системного таймера (это прерывание происходит 100 раз в секунду). В обработчике ядра проверяются все таймеры процессов (и куча других) и если Ваш таймер, выставленный на 2 секунды истек, то будет запланирован вызов функции `alrm`, который и произойдет при очередном возвращении управления из ядра в Ваш процесс. Если во время обработки прерывания системного таймера (и истечения Вашего) ожидания события в системном вызове, запрошенном Вашим процессом не было, то `errno` никто менять не будет.

Например, крутитесь Вы в бесконечном

```
while (errno != EINTR);
```

таймер сработает, `alrm` вызовется (можете даже вывести на экран строчку-другую), но `errno` не изменится (в этом случае ни siginterrupt, ни sigaction **ничего не изменят**). Меняйте его сами в `alrm`, а лучше устанавливайте свой флаг.

[[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr)](/users/3147/alerr), раз уж начали разбираться с сигналами, то почитайте man 7 signal, а также man-ы на sigprocmask, sigsuspend и SEE ALSO к ним.

Comment: Спасибо! Читал я про это всё... Про прерывание не знал...))))

Comment: Одно замечание: одни сисвызовы прерываются, другие нет. read не прерывается по умолчанию. А sleep прервется и errno установится в желаемую EINTR

Comment: @Alerr, почитайте man 7 signal. Там все разжевано. И литературу по программированию в Линуксе.

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну sleep() от alarm()-а естественно прервется. Он и реализован для прерывания от таймера. IMHO он от любого сигнала прервется, наверняка висит в sigsuspend с открытой маской.

По поводу маски сейчас проверю.

Нет. Как-то хитрее. С блокированными сигналами он их игнорирует и продолжает спать. Потом (при восстановлении маски после sleep) pending сигналы доставляются.

Надо будет подумать...

Comment: Я sleep для примера привел.Там еще куча вызовов, которые не возвращаются. И там вообще много чего интересного. См. указанный man 7 signal.

Comment: Почти навскидку: судя по изменению errno (принудительно устанавливаемому в нашем обработчике SIGALRM) на EINTR sleep() использует sigtimedwait с нулевой маской.